# add conditions on mongoose pre-find middleware

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using [mongoose-delete](https://github.com/dsanel/mongoose-delete) plugin.

I want to build a simple [mongoose middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) so I add `{deleted:false}`to every `find` query on that schema.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    mongooseDelete = require('mongoose-delete'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var MySchema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true}
});

MySchema.plugin(mongooseDelete, {deletedAt: true, deletedBy: true});

MySchema.pre('find', function (next){
  // I want to add {deleted: false} to the queries conditions
});
```

How should I implement the pre-find middleware?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In pre-find middleware, `this` is the `Query` object so you can add `{deleted: false}` to the query using:

```
MySchema.pre('find', function() {
    this.where({deleted: false});
});
```

Comment: This wipes out the existing query.  I realize the OP did not ask to add the criteria, but it would be helpful to show adding a new criterion to an existing query.

Comment: @greymatter It doesn't wipe out the existing query, it _adds_ the `deleted: false` query term to the existing query. Just retested it with Mongoose 5.3.7.

Comment: @JohnnyHK is it possible to add the condition to the query of all types of DB operations without having to declare each one? Suppose that no matter the operation (find, findAndUpdate, findOne, save, update, delete, and so...) I always want to add something to the query, is there a global way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

@DomingoSL, you can use a RegEx to implement it to all mongoose methods starting with 'find', for example:

```
MySchema.pre(/^find/, function() {
  this.where({deleted: false});
}
```

Or for any string:

```
MySchema.pre(/.*/, function() {
  this.where({deleted: false});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to implement the same thing, with:

```
MySchema.pre('find', function() {
  this.where({deleted: false});
});
```

as offered by JohnnyHK. It works, but there is a built-in solution directly in [mongoose-delete](https://github.com/dsanel/mongoose-delete). It allows you to override one or multiple methods, which will exclude deleted documents from results. More info [here](https://github.com/dsanel/mongoose-delete#examples-how-to-override-one-or-multiple-methods).

For instance, to achieve Facundo Chambo goal, you could override the `find` method:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    mongooseDelete = require('mongoose-delete'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var MySchema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true}
});

MySchema.plugin(mongooseDelete, {deletedAt: true, deletedBy: true, overrideMethods: ['find']});
```

Only documents with `{deleted: false}` will appear in the results of the `.find()` method.